# AngularJs - show validation message for custom form control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have a custom form control (a directive which is not an input element) which implements ng-model (as suggested [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)) and it works fine. Validation is triggered on the form submit and the directive is made valid/invalid correctly.

The problem is how to display an error message. I tried like for normal form input fields:

```
ng-show="form.fieldName.$error.required"
```

but I cannot access field through name. form.fieldName is undefined.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code... which reproduces your issue

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you defined your form name inside of form tag. After that try to print **formname.fieldname**

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with transclusion. Once I fixed it element was normally accessible through the name.